# Transform XML element if id matches with id on the list from another xml file

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm sorry if the title is not well formed. I have no idea how to make it more precisely to the problem.
I am trying to transform XML file(`file_A.xml`) like this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<offer>
    <products>
        <product>
            <producer/>
            <category/>
            <description>
                <name>name</name>
                <short_desc>short description</short_desc>
            </description>
            <price/>
            <sizes/>
            <images/>
            <iaiext:priority_menu>
                <site id="1">
                    <menu id="1">
                        <item id="757" textId="KOBIETA\Obuwie\Szpilki" level="40000"/>
                    </menu>
                </site>
            </iaiext:priority_menu>
        </product>
        
        <product>
            <producer/>
            <category/>
            <description>
                <name>name</name>
                <short_desc>short description</short_desc>
            </description>
            <price/>
            <sizes/>
            <images/>
            <iaiext:priority_menu>
                <site id="1">
                    <menu id="1">
                        <item id="888" textId="KOBIETA\Obuwie\Szpilki" level="40000"/>
                    </menu>
                </site>
            </iaiext:priority_menu>
        </product>
        
        <product>
        ...
        </product>
        
        <product>
        ...
        </product>
    </products>
</offer>
```

I want to select only products that has item `id` matches with the list of `id` on another xml file(`file_B.xml`) that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FilterList>
  <category_id id="174" name="Botki"/>
  <category_id id="183" name="Kalosze"/>
  <category_id id="757" name="Szpilki"/>
  <category_id id="173" name="Sandały"/>
  <category_id id="185" name="Espadryle"/>
  <category_id id="209" name="Klapki"/>
  <category_id id="818" name="Kapcie"/>
  <category_id id="756" name="Workery"/>
  <category_id id="204" name="Trapery"/>
  <category_id id="206" name="Śniegowce"/>
</FilterList>
```

I managed to be able to get item with specific `ID` by using this in xslt:

```
<xsl:for-each select="offer/products/*">
                <xsl:if test="(description/name and description/name != ''and (iaiext:priority_menu/site/menu/item[@id = '757']))">
                </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But i have no idea how to get all items from `file_A.xml` that matches any `id` from the item's id on the `file_B.xml`

Comment: Your input is not well-formed XML: the prefix `iaiext` must be bound to a namespace.

Comment: Yes and that `iaiext` are automatically generated from our website service provider, so i can't remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<offer>
    <products>
        <product>
            <producer/>
            <category/>
            <description>
                <name>name</name>
                <short_desc>short description</short_desc>
            </description>
            <price/>
            <sizes/>
            <images/>
            <priority_menu>
                <site id="1">
                    <menu id="1">
                        <item id="757" textId="KOBIETA\Obuwie\Szpilki" level="40000"/>
                    </menu>
                </site>
            </priority_menu>
        </product>
        <product>
            <producer/>
            <category/>
            <description>
                <name>name</name>
                <short_desc>short description</short_desc>
            </description>
            <price/>
            <sizes/>
            <images/>
            <priority_menu>
                <site id="1">
                    <menu id="1">
                        <item id="888" textId="KOBIETA\Obuwie\Szpilki" level="40000"/>
                    </menu>
                </site>
            </priority_menu>
        </product>
     </products>
</offer>
```

**file_B.xml**

```
<FilterList>
  <category_id id="174" name="Botki"/>
  <category_id id="183" name="Kalosze"/>
  <category_id id="757" name="Szpilki"/>
  <category_id id="173" name="Sandały"/>
  <category_id id="185" name="Espadryle"/>
  <category_id id="209" name="Klapki"/>
  <category_id id="818" name="Kapcie"/>
  <category_id id="756" name="Workery"/>
  <category_id id="204" name="Trapery"/>
  <category_id id="206" name="Śniegowce"/>
</FilterList>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="product" match="product" use="priority_menu/site/menu/item/@id" />

<xsl:template match="/offer">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('product', document('file_B.xml')/FilterList/category_id/@id)">
             <xsl:copy-of select="."/>  
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <product>
      <producer/>
      <category/>
      <description>
         <name>name</name>
         <short_desc>short description</short_desc>
      </description>
      <price/>
      <sizes/>
      <images/>
      <priority_menu>
         <site id="1">
            <menu id="1">
               <item id="757" textId="KOBIETA\Obuwie\Szpilki" level="40000"/>
            </menu>
         </site>
      </priority_menu>
   </product>
</output>
```